# Secure Database Passwords in PHP Project

Tags: php, database, security, passwords, hide

I Have a PHP Project on Git, that have access some other developers.
The problem is.
1) Developer make changes on project and push it on server or upload it to test server.
2) Developer logins to the test or production machine to run this script.
How can secure the Database Password?
If i make a config file, they can simple add an echo "" command and get the password.
Is there any solution for that? Maybe with group/user permissions in linux? 

Thank you.

Comment: If you don't trust your developers, you must not run their code.

Comment: You probably are not going to find a fool-proof way to do this, and since you are working with other developers, simple ways of hiding this data will probably not work. Solution: Do not give anyone access to your project that you do not trust with it

Comment: If your application has access to the database, and your developers have access to your application, then your developers have access to your database.

Comment: Trust yes.
But if someone developer is active now and after some time has gone, then what happened? Change db password to all machines?
This is painful. And the risk to make damage, big.

Comment: If a developer has left the project, revoke their access to the server. Your database ideally wouldn't be accessible from anywhere else, so even if they have the password there isn't anything they can do with it.

Comment: Yes this is a solution if database user have access to specific ip or localhost. We use hundred of IP's every day. That is a problem to create different user for each ip. If you have mass solutions for that it will be good. Also we use VPNs some times.

Comment: This is more of a systems administration problem. If they have access to servers, then give them SSH access using public/private key pairs. When they leave, revoke their access by removing their public key. Finally, set up a firewall that prevents the database port from being accessed by anyone but the application and database servers. This will ensure that even with the password, they can't use it.

Comment: You all tackle the problem when the person already left. But if the person is still around, that solution doesnt stop the person. I'm afraid there is no easy solution to this. Just dont let any developer onto the test servers, only selected ones. That also doesnt kill the problem, of course.

Comment: I'm not looking for some easy solution off course. I know that the problem is complicated. 
System Administration, ok. If i have specific permissions to devs (only run scripts), is there any solution for automated whitelist?
What i mean. If i add a new machine with some hidden way to be whitelisted to the main db server.

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any real solution using linux security as the web server should always be able to execute the code and php also, so if you leave an ssh access to the production server they would be able to do anything they want on it.

One way to gain some security is to stop using manual login and try using a **CI/CD** with your git, that way you can have a full contrôle on what is executed on, at least, the production server.

That way you can leave access to the tests server, and they should always have that to be able to debug, but they can't execute anything that you did not validate before on the production server. To be sure to not have any issue, you should be the only one, or the sysadmin team should be the only one to have access to the ssh key on the CI.

That's some work to do if you start a CI from scratch and never did it but it will be worth your time when finished and you will also gain in serenity, knowing that no one can access the production without you knowing what is going to get executed on it (that will be the real pain in the ass as you will have to check everything...).

Comment: I'm working a solution to my mind. It is difficult to change whole structure now. Many projects and machines. I'm thinking a scenario like this:
1) Add main db settings and connection to production machines and remove from git
2) When a user push the code to git and after merge with master will sync code with machines.
3) And here i'm working now. Make a layer that user can only execute the script as cli without access to machine.